# What executable files can run on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

What kind of executable files can run on Windows XP through Windows 7?
I know of [PE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable), but I don't know if there are any others.

I'm also interested in knowing different kinds of interpretive executables, like a Java program and such.

I'd also like to know what extensions they use, like PE uses .exe and .dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an "incomplete list" of executable extensions available on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats#Object_code.2C_executable_files.2C_shared_and_dynamically-linked_libraries).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to PE you mentioned, there's also formats used in DOS: [MZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable) and [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file).  Support for the DOS formats are obviously being phased out, but emulators like [DOSBOX](http://www.dosbox.com) attempt to continue support.

As for Java, developers usually supply applications in a [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) format, which is simply a zip file containing all the bytecode and other application resources.